# Calculate Current Angle from Unity ArticulationBody

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to move an *ArticulationDrive* of an *ArticulationBody* using both *targetVelocity* and *targetPosition*. The ArticulationBody has setted with a single revolution (*articulation joint type* setted to *Revolute*)

In particular, I want to rotate the body with *targetVelocity*, and then, when the input from the user stops, I want to set *targetPosition* to the current position of the body so the body can rest in that position.

I try to get the current position from the current angle of the body and pass it to the ArticulationBody, but sometimes ArticulationBody misinterprets the value and does a complete 360 turn.

I try using:

```
Quaternion.Normalize(transform.rotation).eulerAngles.y
```

or

```
Mathf.DeltaAngle(0, Quaternion.Normalize(transform.rotation).eulerAngles.y)
```

but no one is 100% working, in some cases, I get a 360 turn.

**How to set the ArticulationBody target to its Current Angle so no move is necessary?**

Comment: Could you add a bit more of your context and what exactly you are doing there? In general a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) has not 3 but **4 components** `x`, `y`, `z` **and `w`** and works completely different to what you probably are expecting since they all move in the range `-1` to `1` ... Unless you know exactly what you are doing you **never** want to set or access individual components of a `Quaternion`!

Comment: You right! I just wrongly write down the code in the question. I miss *eulerAngles* before getting the *y* component of rotation. I will also edit the question to specify that I'm talking about ArticulationBody with single rotation freedom.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. *ArticulationBody* tracks internally the current position using its speed and movement.

So if you set the *targetVelocity* and the body rotates for two turns, the current position is not 0 but 720. If you set *0* as the target position, the body turns back two times.

I found a method to get the current position directly from the *articulationBody* using the property **[jointPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/ArticulationBody-jointPosition.html)**

In case of articulationBody with *Revolute* you can calculate the current position with this code:

```
float currentPosition= ab.jointPosition[0] * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
```